# What happens if you don't travel after getting a Schengen visa?

Tags: germany, schengen, italy, europe

About 3 years ago I had an Italian Schengen visa for travel for a duration of 2 weeks. Due to an emergency I had to cancel my trip and did not travel. The visa was left unused.

Will this have any consequences on my future chances of approval for Europe visa? I am planning to work in Germany and wanted to know if this could be a reason for denial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this have any consequences on my future chances of approval for Europe visa? I am planning to work in Germany and wanted to know if this could be a reason for denial.

No. You broke no laws and violated no rules. You're under no obligation to travel if issued a visa, you're only under an obligation to comply with the visa conditions *if* you travel.